# check md5 of compressed file without unpacking it completely

Tags: compression, md5

I want to check the integrity of a backup of a Ubuntu disk, copied with dd onto a Windows share. There is not enough space to unpack the backup. Is there a utility to calculate the md5 of a compressed file without unpacking it completely?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This:

```
gzip -d -c myfile.gz | md5sum
```

will stream the decompressed content into md5sum, rather than loading the whole thing into memory.

If it's a zip file, the command is `unzip -p myfile.zip  | md5sum`

Comment: Don't forget to use `md5sum -b` if the uncompressed file is binary.

Comment: if `md5sum` is gnu (eg, linux, mac, and most unix), there will be no difference between "binary" and "text" modes, other than the output will contain an irrelevant asterisk (`*`) for "binary" vs a "space" for "text" next to the filename / or dash (`-`) when reading from stdin (run `md5sum --help` to see if it's gnu or not) https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/md5sum.1.html

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer using `gzip`/`zcat` and piping to md5sum (which someone already posted while I was writing this) will work, but if you want to have more fun, here is a short Perl script which will do the same thing.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Archive::Zip qw/:ERROR_CODES :CONSTANTS/;
use Digest::MD5;

die "Usage: $0 zipfile filename" unless @ARGV == 2;

my $zipfile = $ARGV[0];
my $filename = $ARGV[1];

my $z = Archive::Zip->new();
die "Error reading $zipfile" unless $z->read($zipfile) == AZ_OK;
my $member = $z->memberNamed($filename);
die "Could not find $filename in $zipfile" unless $member;
$member->desiredCompressionMethod(COMPRESSION_STORED);
$member->rewindData();

my $md5 = Digest::MD5->new;
while(1) {
        my($buf,$status) = $member->readChunk();
        $md5->add($$buf) if $status == AZ_STREAM_END || $status == AZ_OK;
        last if $status == AZ_STREAM_END;
        die "IO Error" if $status != AZ_OK;
}
my $digest = $md5->hexdigest;
print "$digest  $zipfile/$filename\n";
```

Answer (score -1):

Is this complicated? My way is, just use

```sh
md5sum file.gz
```

and verify the md5 sum with the one I have, I think this doesn't need to unpack this.
Correct me, If I am wrong.

Comment: What if you don't have the md5sum of the gzipped file?

Comment: If there is no previous md5sum of gzipped file, How do you verify it?

Comment: In my case I had md5sums of files contained in the gzipped file, but not of the gzipped file itself

Comment: @AppajiChintimi gzipped file has metadata which include timestamps. Gzipped files may have different md5sums even if the unzipped data is the same.